# Get the child controls with type T of a control

Tags: c#

I have the following function to get all the child controls of type.

```
    private IEnumerable<Control> GetControlsOfType(Control control, Type type)
    {
        var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

        return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetControlsOfType(ctrl, type))
                                  .Concat(controls)
                                  .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
    }
```

I am trying to convert it using generic type parameter.

```
    private IEnumerable<T> GetControlsOfType<T>(Control control) where T: Control
    {
        var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

        return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetControlsOfType<T>(ctrl))
                                  .Concat(controls)
                                  .Where(c => c.GetType() == T);
    }
```

The code has the error on `.Concat`.

> Error 6   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`<T`>' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Concat' and the best extension method overload
>   'System.Linq.Queryable.Concat`<TSource`>(System.Linq.IQueryable`<TSource`>,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`<TSource`>)' has some invalid
>   arguments

How to fix the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `.OfType<Control>()` after `GetControlsOfType<T>(ctrl)` and instead of your `Where`

So your code reads:

```
return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetControlsOfType<T>(ctrl).OfType<Control>())
                                  .Concat(controls)
                                  .OfType<T>();
```

Comment: He wants to return `IEnumerable<T>` -- won't this return `IEnumerable<Control>`?

Comment: `GetControlsOfType<T>(ctrl)` already has the type of `IEnumerable<Control>`. Why `OfType<Control>()` is needed here?

Comment: @NickW Because `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Concat'`, however, `IEnumerable<Control>` does. You'll often find the same problem with `Collection`s with the same workaround :)

Comment: @dav_i Interesting, curious why Microsoft didn't create `Concat` for `IEnumerable<T>`.